# Increment String Value Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets-macros

Using the following code I cannot increment a value in google sheets to be plus one.

```
function incrementCellValuesByOne() {
  // Increments the values in all the cells in the active range (i.e., selected cells).
  // Numbers increase by one, text strings get a "1" appended.
  // Cells that contain a formula are ignored.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeRange = ss.getActiveRange();
  var cell, cellValue, cellFormula;

  // iterate through all cells in the active range
  for (var cellRow = 1; cellRow <= activeRange.getHeight(); cellRow++) {
    for (var cellColumn = 1; cellColumn <= activeRange.getWidth(); cellColumn++) {
      cell = activeRange.getCell(cellRow, cellColumn);
      cellFormula = cell.getFormula();

      // if not a formula, increment numbers by one, or add "1" to text strings
      // if the leftmost character is "=", it contains a formula and is ignored
      // otherwise, the cell contains a constant and is safe to increment
      // does not work correctly with cells that start with '=
      if (cellFormula[0] != "=") {
        cellValue = cell.getValue();
        cellValue =+cellValue
        cell.setValue(cellValue + 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For example "personalDataDOB_3" needs to become "personalDaTaDOB_4" I'm looking for a fast way to do this as right now I need to replace the value by typing.

Answer (score 0):

You want to modify "personalDataDOB_3" of a certain cell to "personalDaTaDOB_4". If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- When the retrieved "personalDataDOB_3" is converted to the number using `cellValue =+cellValue`, `NaN` is returned. So even if 1 was added, the result is `NaN`.
- If the format of strings you want to modify is always "personalDataDOB_#", how about separating the string by `_`?

In order to reflect above points, please modify your script as follows.

#### From :

```
if (cellFormula[0] != "=") {
  cellValue = cell.getValue();
  cellValue =+cellValue
  cell.setValue(cellValue + 1);
}
```

#### To :

```
if (cellFormula[0] != "=") {
  cellValue = cell.getValue();
  var temp = cellValue.split("_"); // Added
  temp[1] = Number(temp[1]) + 1; // Added
  cell.setValue(temp.join("_")); // Modified
}
```

#### Note :

- If the format of strings you want to modify is always changed, please tell me.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.